# Python Function Recursive - Give Index of first occurence of 'number' in 'list' AND return None if number not in list

Tags: python, recursion

I have an exercice where I need to find the index of the first occurence of a number in list. But I also need to return `None` if index can't be found, meaning the number is not in list.
I need to do that with a recursive function in Python.

I already created a code that does: "find the index of the first occurence of a number in list". And it works.

```
def index(lst, number_find):
    if lst == []:
        return None
    elif lst[0] == number_find:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1 + index(lst[1:], number_find)

liste = range(51)
print(index(liste, 42))
```

But I can't write the code that manages the case if the number is not in list.
I have done that:

```
def index(lst, number_find):
    if number_find not in lst: 
        return None
    elif lst == []:
        return None
    elif lst[0] == number_find:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1 + index(lst[1:], number_find)

liste = range(51)
print(index(liste, 42))
```

But the use of "not in" is not good here for me because that seems to use some iterative code that I can't use.

Comment: When you call `index(lst[1:], number_find)`, check if it returns None.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to protect against the case where `None` comes back from the recursive call, because `1 + None` will raise a `TypeError`:

```
def index(lst, number_find):
    if lst == []:
        return None
    elif lst[0] == number_find:
        return 0
    else:
        i = index(lst[1:], number_find)
        if i is not None:
            return 1 + i
        return None  # not strictly necessary as None returned implicity
```

Of course, when you return from every `if`-block, you can omit any `else`. Also, `None` is the default return value, so you can shorten your logic

```
def index(lst, number_find):
    if lst:
        if lst[0] == number_find:
            return 0
        if (i := index(lst[1:], number_find)) is not None:
            return 1 + i
```

Btw, since slicing is `O(N)` here, all these approaches are quadratic. So here is a solution that has linear complexity:

```
def index(lst, number_find):
    def rec(it, i=0):
        if (n := next(it, None)) is not None:
            return i if n == number_find else rec(it, i+1)
    return rec(iter(lst))
```

Comment: I second every advice given in this answer, except the advice to rely on the implicit `return None`. I think explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: @Stef Depends! When reviewing code at work, I would always ask for the first as readability and maintainability count for a lot in production code (e.g. the `return None` line is pure gold when following code in a debugger). But for an academic exercise or code competition, I'd always go for poetic density and showing off your understanding :P

Comment: @Stef I added a linear approach as the unnecessary quadratic complexity has gone unmentioend so far. I appropriated your approach of passing the index to the rec call ;)

Comment: Yes but at this points the conclusion is "don't use recursion in python" ;)

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer by user2390182 explains in detail how to handle the possible `None` value returned by the recursive call.

A different approach is to write the function in a tail-recursive way:

```py
def index(lst, number_find, acc=0):
  if lst == []:
    return None
  elif lst[0] == number_find:
    return acc
  else:
    return index(lst[1:], number_find, acc+1)
```

Note that python doesn't perform tail-rec optimization; but this approach still avoids the `1+None` issue.

Comment: Very valid alternative.